# How to deactivate django plugin for some tests?

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

I'm running some tests for Django, and some other tests for the website using Selenium.

My choice of Testing framework is amazing [Pytest](http://pytest.org/latest).

for testing Django I've currently installed [pytest-django plugin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-django) and tests for Django run as expected, **however** now I'm back to my previous tests that don't need Django plugin.

I start tests and the Django plugin is picked up automatically.
I've checked the documentation and found [the article](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#deactivating-unregistering-a-plugin-by-name) where it is explained how to disable\deactivate plugins, however when I run this command:

```
py.test -p no:django
```

I get an error that my "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" is not on sys.path.

Also

commands like:

```
py.test --traceconfig
```

or

```
py.test --version
```

throw me the same error.
Looks like Django plugin is getting to deep? Why is it called when I'm just checking the version or the 'installed plugins'?

QUESTION: Is there any way to temporary deactivate this plugin without uninstalling it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work.  When i install pytest-2.3.4 and run `py.test -p no:django --version` i don't get the DJANGO_SETTINGS issues.  I get it when i leave away the `-p no:django` disabling.
If it doesn't work, please link to a full trace on a pastebin.

Comment: I've actually tried it before... just now noticed that I was trying `no:dajngo` instead of `no:django`. Thanks Holger.

Comment: ended up using: `plgns = [tests.myplugin]
    pytest.main(sys.argv[1:] + ['-p','no:django'], plugins=plgns)`

Answer (score 0):

IIRC this is because of a combination of things:

- On startup py.test looks for the setuptool entrypoint "pytest11"
- Entrypoints get imported before they get activated or deactivated
- pytest-django (as released, currently 1.4) does a load of Django imports upfront
- A lot of Django needs the settings module configured even at import time

Unfortunately this is unavoidable in the released version of pytest-django.  And the answer originally was: no, run the pytest-django and other tests in different virtualenvs.

However it is also the reason we started work on a version of the plugin which avoids these problems.  What I consider the best version right now is the pytest23 branch at https://github.com/flub/pytest_django  This version is pretty feature complete, certainly compared to the released version, it just needs a little more polishing mainly on the tests and documentation.

I believe/hope that within the next few weeks this branch will be merged and released, I just need to get Andreas to have a look through and agree.  I consider it certainly stable enough to start using.

Comment: Oh, just saw Holger's reply.  It appears step 2 is not happening in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try using virtualenv with django at first, as you suggest, but ran into problems installing `MySQLdb`. I'm using windows and I kept failing to create MSI out of source. So I just installed it from binary.